# DES-X library for C (implementation on µController)

Tags: encryption, des

I am searching for a c-library to decode and encode with DES-X. 
Unfortunately i can't find any...
Can you please let me know if anything is out there?
It has to be DES-X.

Comment: GNU library, google it

Comment: Thank you for your answere. My Problem was, that they only implemented DES not DES-X. However after some research i found out, that DESX just uses key widening over DES so if someone has the same problem you just have to calc a input and output widening key which is simply straight Forward and use it on the DES... I implemented it in matlab and translated it into c Code. On request i am going to share the Code. (note that the Code translated from matlab is not very efficient) For future Projects i recommend to use Hardware like xor Features.